# Trying to identify selected table view cells

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios6, uitableview

I'm trying to find selected people in an array. I'm correctly getting where no one is selected, however, if one person in a group is selected, all people in the group are selected.

After a long head-scratching session, I could use some help to see if there is something obvious.

This action is going on in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    static NSString *pCell = @"Cell";

    PeopleCell *cell = (PeopleCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:pCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PeopleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:pCell];
    }

    people = [peopleArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *text = [people objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;

    if (selectedPeopleinGroup.count == 0) {
        //no people selected in this group
        NSLog(@"none");
        cell.isSelected = [selectedPeopleinGroup containsObject:text] == NO;       
    } else {
        //there are some people in this group - find out who they are
        NSLog(@"some");
        NSString *key1 =   [selectedPeopleinGroup valueForKey:@"personKey"];
        NSString *key2 = [people valueForKey:@"personKey"];

        NSLog (@"key1 %@", key1 );
        NSLog (@"key2 %@", key2 );

        if (key1 == key2) {
            cell.isSelected = [selectedPeople containsObject:text] == YES;
        } else {
            cell.isSelected = [selectedPeople containsObject:text] == NO;
        }

    }

    return cell;

}
```

The cell is a subclassed UITableViewCell that has a checkmark image on the left side of the cell if selected and a different image if not selected. Many thanks.

Comment: `selectedPeopleInGroup`. Is this an array or a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks odd:

```
NSString *key1 =   [selectedPeopleinGroup valueForKey:@"personKey"];
```

if `selectedPeopleInGroup` is an array, then `valueForKey:` returns an array of the results of calling `valueForKey` on each object in the array. So you are assigning an array to a string.

I'm surprised that the compiler is not issuing a warning about this. I'm also surprised that the log statements don't show odd values.

Comment: interesting. no compiler errors/warnings, but the logs are interesting:  key1 ( 061613232405)
 key2 061613232404

 key1 ( 061613232405)
 key2 061613232405

Comment: Thanks Abizern, you nailed it. I have to iterate through the selectedPeopleInGroup array to get the comparison string.